# Phonegap image not displayed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I have done an app in Phonegap 1.4 with Xcode it works fine.

Now I am testing the app on iPhone. The first time all images displayed on the screen, if I go to other page and come back, the image is not displayed. I do not know why. It works fine in Xcode simulator. The image is (if click change in to other image). 
The coding is:

```
$("#jsEmployerRole").click(function(e){

                             $("#jsEmployeeTick").attr("src",'dulTick.png');
                             $("#jsEmployerTick").attr("src",'Tick.png');


                             });
    $("#jsEmployeeRole").click(function(e){
                          $("#jsEmployeeTick").attr("src",'Tick.png');
                             $("#jsEmployerTick").attr("src",'dulTick.png');

                             });
```

Comment: ok can you help me if i change the image via code it is not display in iPhone it displays question mark.. help me